# Linker issue GNU LD

Tags: assembly, makefile, linker, gnu-make, gnu-assembler

I am having some problems with GNU ld. I generate the object files and wish to link them together to form an ELF file.

However, I get an odd error whilst linking:

```
    seraphim@Axe:~/awork/local/MD/example$ make

m68k-elf-as -D -R -mcpu=68000 -march=68000 --bitwise-or --traditional-format --register-prefix-optional --statistics -I /home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/src -a=/home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/listing/jolly.lst -g /home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/src/jolly.s -o /home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/obj/jolly.o

m68k-elf-as: total time in assembly: 0.008000
m68k-elf-as: data size 724992
frag chains:

    0xa06ed18 .text               1976 frags

    0xa06edb0 .bss                   6 frags

    0xa06ef2c .bss                   4 frags

    0xa06ef78 .debug_line          329 frags

    0xa06efc4 .debug_info            2 frags

    0xa06f010 .debug_abbrev          2 frags

    0xa06f05c .debug_aranges             3 frags

fixups: 152
1 mini local symbols created, 0 converted
m68k-elf-as -D -R -mcpu=68000 -march=68000 --bitwise-or --traditional-format --register-prefix-optional --statistics -I /home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/src -a=/home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/listing/sega.lst -g /home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/src/sega.s -o /home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/obj/sega.o

m68k-elf-as: total time in assembly: 0.004000
m68k-elf-as: data size 667648
frag chains:

    0x8d4dd10 .text               1267 frags

    0x8d4dda8 .bss                   2 frags

    0x8d4df24 .debug_line          289 frags

    0x8d4df70 .debug_info            2 frags

    0x8d4dfbc .debug_abbrev          2 frags

    0x8d4e008 .debug_aranges             3 frags

fixups: 137
1 mini local symbols created, 0 converted
m68k-elf-ld -T /home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/linker/md_gas_axlib2.ld -o /home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/elf/jolly.elf -Map=/home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/map/jolly.map -nostdlib --warn-common --whole-archive --cref -L /home/seraphim/awork/local/proj/example/lib -l axlib2

.: file not recognized: Is a directory
make: *** [jolly.elf] Error 1
```

Does anyone have similar experiences and have any idea what ld is complaining about?

Comment: Is the error actually from the last command? Have you tried running it by itself from a prompt?

Comment: Yes, it is an error raised during the linking stage by m68k-elf-ld.  Running from a prompt?  I have only run everything from a Terminal - do you mean something else?

Comment: Is your linker script correct?

Comment: That got me thinking as the Makefile was not altered too much as I worked on the project but I did change the linker-script a bit.  I tried it with a script from an older project but it failed still.  Sorry, I know what you mean by trying it from the prompt; to try to execute the commands from the CLI without the Makefile to see if it works as expected.  The other option is for me to try out a dummy project and recreate the steps to try to determine why it fails.  It is a bit of a mystery at present.

Comment: You should post the linker script.